# Matching one of three letters on one side of an underscore if not preceded or followed with alphanumerics

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have two phrases:

```
V_AEH1_N
S_D_R_AXH0
```

This is my regex so far:

```
r"(_(N|D|S)(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9]))|((?=[^a-zA-Z0-9])(N|D|S)_)"
```

which mathces only **_D** in the 2nd phrase. The desired outcome is to match both **S_** & **D_** and also **_N** from the first phrase.

Comment: What do they have in common?

Comment: I added a verbal explanation of the attempted pattern. In this case, it is quite clear what is meant from the pattern and two finite examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<![^\W_])[NDS]_|_[NDS](?![^\W_])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SpUERL/1). *Details*:

- `(?<![^\W_])[NDS]_` - `N`, `D` or `S` and an underscore after if not preceded with a non-alphanumeric char (`(?<![^\W_])` is a leading word boundary here with `_` "subtracted" from it)
- `|` - or
- `_[NDS](?![^\W_])` - an underscore and then either `N`, `D` or `S` if not followed with a non-alphanumeric char (`(?![^\W_])` is a trailing word boundary here with `_` "subtracted" from it).